# /etc/locale.gen: No such file or directory, how can I add a new locale the right way

Tags: 14.04, locale

The file `/etc/locale.gen` does not exist on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, how can I add a new locale the right way ?

Comment: +1 This is true. `/etc/locale.gen` is first used in 16.04 LTS and that is not used in 14.04 LTS.

Comment: For desktop, the recommended way to add locale is from Settings > Language Support. Else for server, refer to the linked possible duplicate.

Comment: @clearkimura: No it's not. It's the very same command as for server.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new locale, you have to add it to */etc/locale.gen*, save the file and run following command:

```
sudo locale-gen
```

But it is really strange, that this file is missing on your system.

Add this for American-English:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

/etc/locale.gen contains all local settings and system languages in a commented format.

To add `/etc/locale.gen` the right way, run the command

```
$ sudo apt install locale-gen --reinstall
```

The output would be

```
$ sudo apt install locales --reinstall
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Need to get 3,612 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
  Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 locales all 2.27-3ubuntu1 [3,612 kB]
  Fetched 3,612 kB in 17s (213 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                           
  Preconfiguring packages ...
  (Reading database ... 264543 files and directories currently installed.)
  Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.27-3ubuntu1_all.deb ...
  Unpacking locales (2.27-3ubuntu1) over (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
  Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
  Setting up locales (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
  Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IL.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
  Generation complete.
```

For more information - https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Linux/locale